# CSS only tabs - How can I add a border-top-left-radius to the tab content only when tab 2, 3 & 4 are activated?

Tags: html, css

CSS only! Does anyone know how to trigger add an 8px radius to the top left of the .tab-content container only when tab 2, 3, or 4 are pressed and leave it without a radius when tab-1 is selected?

'border-top-left-radius: 8px;' is the code I need to execute, only when these mentioned tabs are selected and not the 1st tab.

I have tried many different approaches here relating to .tab-switch:checked and the same with .tab-content but cant get anything to fire.

```css
:root {
  --primary: #0062a4;
  --primary_med: #5084a7;
  --primary_dark: #24435c;
  --light: #ffffff;
  --dark: #000000;
  --shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

.feedback {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(23, 62, 136), rgb(0, 140, 255));
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs::before,
.tabs::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.tabs::after {
  clear: both;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  Padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tab-switch {
  display: none;
}

.tab-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--primary_dark);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

.tab-switch:checked+.tab-label {
  background: var(--primary_med);
  color: var(--light);
  border-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -0.0625rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tab-content {
  height: 12rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3.1em;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.618rem;
  background: var(--primary_med);
  opacity: 0;
  height: 422px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-switch:checked+label+.tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.base-footer {
  gap: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(23, 62, 136), rgb(0, 140, 255));
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-1" checked class="tab-switch">
      <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label">Tab 1</label>
      <div class="tab-content">Tab 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-2" class="tab-switch">
      <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label">Tab 2</label>
      <div class="tab-content">Tab 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-3" class="tab-switch">
      <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label">Tab 3</label>
      <div class="tab-content">Tab 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-4" class="tab-switch">
      <label for="tab-4" class="tab-label">Tab 4</label>
      <div class="tab-content">Tab 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need a solution in CSS only please.

Comment: Or alternatively add a small Square in the top left of the content container to cover up the corner radius...and do this only when tab 1 is selected. There has to be a way to do this without JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the :not selector - what you want to select are the tabs that are checked but are not the first-child (of the .tabs element).

```css
    :root {
      --primary: #0062a4;
      --primary_med: #5084a7;
      --primary_dark: #24435c;
      --light: #ffffff;
      --dark: #000000;
      --shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
    }

    .feedback {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(23, 62, 136), rgb(0, 140, 255));
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px;
    }

    .tabs {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .tabs::before,
    .tabs::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
    }

    .tabs::after {
      clear: both;
    }

    .tab {
      float: left;
      Padding-top: 5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .tab-switch {
      display: none;
    }

    .tab-label {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 34px;
      text-align: center;
      background: var(--primary_dark);
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-top-left-radius: 8px;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    }

    .tab-switch:checked+.tab-label {
      background: var(--primary_med);
      color: var(--light);
      border-bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      top: -0.0625rem;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .tab-content {
      height: 12rem;
      position: absolute;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 3.1em;
      left: 0;
      padding: 1.618rem;
      background: var(--primary_med);
      opacity: 0;
      height: 422px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .tab-switch:checked+label+.tab-content {
      z-index: 2;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .tab:not(:first-child) .tab-switch:checked+label+.tab-content {
      border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    }


    .base-footer {
      gap: 10px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(23, 62, 136), rgb(0, 140, 255));
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab">
          <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-1" checked class="tab-switch">
          <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label">Tab 1</label>
          <div class="tab-content">Tab 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
          <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-2" class="tab-switch">
          <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label">Tab 2</label>
          <div class="tab-content">Tab 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
          <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-3" class="tab-switch">
          <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label">Tab 3</label>
          <div class="tab-content">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
          <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-4" class="tab-switch">
          <label for="tab-4" class="tab-label">Tab 4</label>
          <div class="tab-content">Tab 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```